# Logarithm inequality where is mistake

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Solve inequality

> $\log_x\left[\log_2\left(4^x-6\right)\right]\le1$

$\log_x\left[\log_2\left(4^x-6\right)\right]\le\log_xx$
$4^x-6>0\Rightarrow x>\log_46 $
For $x\in(0;1)$
$\log_x\left[\log_2\left(4^x-6\right)\right]\le\log_xx\\\log_2(4^x-6)\ge x\\4^x-6\ge2^x\Rightarrow4^x-2^x-6\ge0\Rightarrow(2^x-3)(2^x+2)\ge0 \Rightarrow 2^x\ge3\Rightarrow x\ge\log_23\not\in(0;1)$
For $x\in(1;\infty) \wedge x>\log_46 \Rightarrow x\in(\log_46;\infty)$
$\log_x\left[\log_2\left(4^x-6\right)\right]\le\log_xx\\\log_2(4^x-6)\le x\\4^x-6\le2^x\Rightarrow 4^x-2^x-6\le0\Rightarrow (2^x-3)(2^x+2)\le0 \Rightarrow 2^x\le3 \Rightarrow x\le\log_23\\\log_46...\log_23,\frac{\log_26}{\log_24}...\frac{\log_23}{\log_22},\frac{\log_26}{2}...\frac{\log_23}{1},\log_2\sqrt{6}..<.\log_23\\\Rightarrow x\in(\log_46;\log_23\rangle$
But wolfram say: $x\in\langle\log_2\sqrt{7};\log_23\rangle$
What I do wrong?

Comment: Just because $x > \log_4 6$ doesn't mean that $x$ can be as low as $\log_4 6$.  After all, $x > 1$ and $x > 0$ and $x > -5,126$ but the range $\langle-5126, 1\rangle$ are *not* acceptable values for $x$.  And apparently $\langle\log_4 6, \log_2\sqrt 7]$ is not an acceptable range.  Probably for reasons you have not considered.

Comment: $\log_4 6 < \log_2 \sqrt 7$ so $\langle\log_2\sqrt{7};\log_23\rangle\subsetneq \langle \log_4 6; \log_2 3\rangle$ and you answer is not incorrect;  $x$ *is*  in $\langle\log_2\sqrt{7};\log_23\rangle \subseteq  \langle \log_4 6; \log_2 3\rangle$.  But your answer isn't complete.  Apparently $x \not \in (\log_4 6; \log_2 \sqrt {7}]$ for reasons you have not yet addressed.  Keep going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly used $4^x-6>0\Rightarrow x>\log_46$.

However $4^x-6$ must be greater than this because we need $\log_2(4^x-6)> 0.$

Therefore we must have $4^x-6>1$ i.e. $4^x>7$ which gives Wolfram's answer.